# "Write a Java program to compute the area of a polygon." - getting a different solution than www.w3resource.com

Tags: java

Here's the exercise:

```
35. Write a Java program to compute the area of a polygon. Go to the editor
Area of a polygon = (n*s^2)/(4*tan(π/n))
where n is n-sided polygon and s is the length of a side
Input Data:
Input the number of sides on the polygon: 7
Input the length of one of the sides: 6
Expected Output

The area is: 130.82084798405722
```

My code returns 127.30573435631248 (length = 7, sides = 6)
The code on the website returns 130.82084798405722 (length = 7, sides = 6)

I'm having trouble seeing why mine is different from theirs...

Any ideas?

**Here's my code:**

```
public static void exercise35(){
    int number1 = integerInput(); //set to 7, length
    int sides = integerInput(); //set to 6, sides

    double area = (sides * (number1 * number1)) / (4.0 * Math.tan((Math.PI / sides)));

    System.out.println("The area of a polygon with " + sides + " sides of length " + number1 + " = " + area);
}
```

**Here's the solution from http://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/index.php (exercise #35)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise35 {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the number of sides on the polygon: ");
        int ns = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the length of one of the sides: ");
        double side = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("The area is: " + polygonArea(ns, side)+"\n");
    }
    public static double polygonArea(int ns, double side) {
        return (ns * (side * side)) / (4.0 * Math.tan((Math.PI / ns)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Comment: What is the data type for your "sides" vs. the "ns" variable in the example? (the solution cheated to make it easier)

Comment: have you tried using a good old calculator to see who's right?

Comment: a bit more effort before asking is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You mixed sides and number in the formula.

That teaches an interesting lesson of programming: "*Give sensible names to variables*".

Answer (score 0):

Change 6 and 7 and you'll get the answer you want : ) And in the future, please try debugging your code first to see what's going on.